# Adding unique labels with matplotlib in for loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, matplotlib, label

Is it possible to add a different label to each line that's plotted in a for loop? I want the label to depend on the iterating element `i`. Say I have a list of length 4 called `my_list`, and I want to do the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
other_list = [[1, 1.2, 1.4, 1.6], [0.8, 0.9, 0.7, 0.6], [1.9, 1.3, 1.4, 1.0], [0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6]]

for i in range(len(my_list)):
    plt.plot(my_list, other_list[i], label='Line %s' % i)
plt.legend('upper left')
```

I want the labels to appear as `Line 0`, ..., `Line 3` depending on what `i` is in the loop. But I'm not getting this -- my labels are appearing as letters `u`, `p`, `p`, and `e` for some reason. I've also tried `label='Line'+str(i)`, and got the same output.

Comment: Try `plt.legend(loc='upper left')`

Comment: Thanks, it works now. Do you know why it labeled the lines with those letters until I fixed the legend command? It's strange since the legend still showed up.

Comment: It iterated over the string `'upper left'` which yielded characters, and it took the first four because there's four plots.